# Javascript Constructor and appending the results into a table in HTML

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am relatively new to coding. I am attempting to push the results I get from a random generator function which will have calculated the results from the min and max numbers of customers manually inputted.

The issue I have run into is that, though I have made it so that the results gets pushed into the empty arrays. When I console log, the object created from the constructor. There is no data being being pushed.

```js
const hour = ["6am","7am","8am","9am","10am","11am","12pm","1pm","2pm","3pm","4pm","5pm","6pm","7pm",];
//NOTE: Constructor
function Location(city,minmax, averageConversionRate_cookieValue) {
  this.name = city;
  this.customerRange = [minmax[0], minmax[1]];
  this.averageConversionRate_cookieValue = averageConversionRate_cookieValue;
  this.customerEachRange = [];
  this.cookiesSoldEachHour = [];
  this.totalDailyCookies = 0;
}

//NOTE: Prototype
Location.prototype = {
  constructor: Location,
  estimatedCustomer_perHour: function() {
    for (let a = 0; a < hour.length; a++) {
      this.customersEachHour.push(
        random(this.customerRange[0], this.customerRange[1])
      );
    }
  },
  cookiesPurchased_oneHour: function () {
    for (let a = 0; a < this.customersEachHour.length; a++) {
      this.cookiesSoldEachHour.push(
        Math.floor(
          this.customersEachHour[a] * this.averageConversionRate_cookieValue
        )
      );
    }
  },
  changeCusRange: function (min, max) {
    return (this.customerRange = [min, max]);
  },
  render() {
    this.estimatedCustomer_perHour();
    this.cookiesPurchased_oneHour();
    const unorderedList = document.getElementById("seattle");
    for (let a = 0; a < this.customersEachHour.length; a++) {
      const listTable = document.createElement("tr");
      listItem.textContent = `${hour[a]}: ${this.customersEachHour[a]} cookies`;
      unorderedList.appendChild(listItem);
      this.totalDailyCookies =
        this.totalDailyCookies + this.customersEachHour[a];
    }
    const listTable = document.createElement("tr");
    listTable.textContent = `Total: ${this.totalDailyCookies} cookies`;
    unorderedList.appendChild(listItem);
  },
}

//NOTE: Random fn()
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

//NOTE: Object creation
const seattle = new Location('Seattle', [23,65], 6.3);
const tokyo = new Location('tokyo',[3,24],1.2);
const dubai = new Location('dubai',[11,38],3.7);
const paris = new Location('paris',[20,38],2.3);
const lima = new Location('lima',[2,16],4.6)

console.log(seattle)
```

Comment: Data is only pushed into your arrays when you call your methods on your prototype, eg: `seattle.estimatedCustomer_perHour()`

Comment: Isn't that what render() in prototype is doing?

Comment: Oh yes, I missed that. But it doesn't look like you're calling `.render()` in your code anywhere (eg: `seattle.render()`?)

Comment: FYI: `render() {` is equivalent to  `render: function() {` its function declaration, doesn't actually call the function

Comment: I appreciate the info. This closes the question I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spotted **numerous** problems with your code... `listItem` and `this.customersEachHour` are both `undefined`. You have hardcoded the value `seattle` as an `id` in `render` (which you never even call). You create a `<tr>` element for some reason but never use it. Also, you should simply wrap all of this into a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

```js
const hour = ["6am","7am","8am","9am","10am","11am","12pm","1pm","2pm","3pm","4pm","5pm","6pm","7pm"];

function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

class Location {
  constructor(city, minmax, averageConversionRate_cookieValue) {
    this.name = city;
    this.list = document.getElementById(this.name);
    this.customerRange = [minmax[0], minmax[1]];
    this.averageConversionRate_cookieValue = averageConversionRate_cookieValue;
    this.customersEachHour = [];
    this.cookiesSoldEachHour = [];
    this.totalDailyCookies = 0;
    this.render();
  }
  
  estimatedCustomer_perHour() {
    for (let a = 0; a < hour.length; a++) {
      this.customersEachHour.push(
        random(this.customerRange[0], this.customerRange[1])
      );
    }
  }
  
  cookiesPurchased_oneHour() {
    for (let a = 0; a < this.customersEachHour.length; a++) {
      this.cookiesSoldEachHour.push(
        Math.floor(
          this.customersEachHour[a] * this.averageConversionRate_cookieValue
        )
      );
    }
  }
  
  changeCusRange(min, max) {
    return (this.customerRange = [min, max]);
  }
  
  render() {
    this.estimatedCustomer_perHour();
    this.cookiesPurchased_oneHour();
    for (let a = 0; a < this.customersEachHour.length; a++) {
      let item = document.createElement("li");
      item.textContent = `${hour[a]}: ${this.customersEachHour[a]} cookies`;
      this.list.append(item);
      this.totalDailyCookies = this.totalDailyCookies + this.customersEachHour[a];
    }
    let total = document.createElement("li");
    total.textContent = `Total: ${this.totalDailyCookies} cookies`;
    this.list.append(total);
  }
}

const seattle = new Location('Seattle', [23,65], 6.3);

console.log(seattle);
```

```html
<ul id="Seattle"></ul>
```

Comment: You are right. I am attempting to create a table which has it's data coming from inputted data. ie. The issue is, the class was rushed and now I am having to do the hard work by myself and figure how to do this. Thanks for the code above.

Comment: If my code helped, please upvote my answer. That is the best way to thank me.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried to do upon reading your reply and code, unfortunately I don't have enough credit to do so.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that you need [at least 15 rep to upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). However, you do have the ability to accept the answer as the correct solution by clicking the checkmark below the vote arrows.

Comment: Once again thank you for more info. The check mark has been marked.. pan intended and until next time.